# Webgl to aggregate data

Tags: webgl, aggregation, blend

I have a rendering pipeline setup in WebGL and I would like to count how many times are vertices from VBO rendered to a particular pixel. My idea is to use a blending for that so that I can derive such a number from the pixel rgba value by reading the pixel after the rendering is done.

Say in fragment shader I have:
`gl_FragColor = vec4(1./(256.),0., 0., 0.);`

Then I use the 
`gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE);`

So once the vertex is rendered two times to one pixel the pixel R value will be equal to 2. Such an approach works, but I'm limited by the number of 256 that it the largest possible value for each pixel color. Is there a way to configure blending function so that I can handle anyhow other values? Theoretically 256^4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Solved.... Enabling the `gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float")` enables to render to offscreen buffer with texture of type `gl.FLOAT`.

So the texture looks like `gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);`

Then the reading of the pixels can be done as:

```
var readout = new Float32Array(width * height * 4);     
gl.readPixels(0, 0, width ,height, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, readout);
```

That's it.

Comment: I suggest you to mark your question as answered with your answer, this will help to keep this question alive on StackOverflow :)